# Self-energy of an infinite conducting charged plate

Tags: electrostatics, energy, electric-circuits, capacitance, conductors

When we write the energy loss due to closing the switch in an $RC$ circuit, we find the difference between the initial and final *energies of interaction* between the two plates of the parallel plate capacitor. Why is the change in ***self-energy*** **of an individual plate** (i.e the energy of interaction between the charges of the same plate) not taken into consideration?

Comment: If the energy between two parallel plates are calculated from integrating $E^2$, it has already included the self-energy of charges within each plate.

Comment: @verdelite So it contains all? I mean, all the energies of interaction? For any general body?

Comment: Yes if you integrate over all space where $E^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @verdelite Got it. Thanks.